# Extracting link from a facebook page

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, ajax, facebook

I want to extract content of a facebook page mainly the links in a facebook page. I tried extracting using jsoup but it does not show the relevant link the link which is showing the likes for the topic for eg :https://www.facebook.com/search/109301862430120/likers.may be it's a jquery,ajax or javascript type code. So how can I extract those link using java how can i extract/access that link or calling a JavaScript function with HTMLUnit

```
public static void main(String args[])
{
        Testing t=new Testing();
        t.traceLink();
        }

public static void traceLink() 
{
// File input = new File("/tmp/input.html");
Document doc = null;
    try
    {
    doc = Jsoup.connect("https://www.facebook.com
/pages/Ice-cream/109301862430120?rf=102173023157556").get();
    Elements link = doc.select("a[href]");
    String stringLink = null;

    for (int i = 0; i < link.size(); i++) 
    {

        stringLink = link.toString();
        System.out.println(stringLink);
    }}}

    System.out.println(link);
    }
    catch (IOException e) 
    {
    //e.printStackTrace();
    }
Element links = doc.select("a[href]").first();
System.out.println(links);
```

Comment: do it with facebook graph api

Comment: proxify request server side

Comment: @wayne it's not possible using restfb or facebook4j.I alredy tried it

Comment: @A.Wolff i didn't get u

Comment: It's very hasrd to understand what you want to do, because the code you're showing doesn't match your explanations

Comment: @Tobi i don't knw why u didn't get this I just want to extract the  above link using my code. It does't show the above link since it's not html

Comment: another screen scrape. I never use Jsoup, I just try their online version http://try.jsoup.org/. you can see the html downloaded is not complete. Jsoup is html parser not headless browser like phantomjs, it only download the html not resolving all ajax/css/js. phantomjs will work, but it is not consistently reliable.
facebook graph api not getting the result because that page is a generated page by facebook, it got a different ID. I don't know what's the id but once you know how to get that you can stay away from scraping.

Comment: Well, for example the link for your search isn't working, just for a start.

Comment: the link is https://www.facebook.com/search/109301862430120/likers without .may

Comment: @wayne k wahtever can I extract link using java